# Are there equivalent in Java of ASP.NET control caching and Post-cache substitution

Tags: java, asp.net, jsp, servlets

See here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/h30h475z(v=vs.90).aspx

> In control caching, also known as fragment caching, you can cache
>   parts of the page output by creating user controls to contain the
>   cached content and then marking the user controls as cacheable. This
>   allows specific content within a page to be cached, while the overall
>   page is recreated each time.
>
> Post-cache substitution is the opposite. The page is cached, but
>   fragments within the page are dynamic and should therefore not be
>   cached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Post-cache substitution you mentioned

For partial webpage caching you can use [EH Cache](http://ehcache.org/) or [OS Cache Tags](http://www.opensymphony.com/).

OS Cache is now dead but you can download the libraries. Its easy to use.

Your app server may provide its own cache libraries. For example, Websphere provides [cache libraries](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wchelp/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.commerce.admin.doc%2Fconcepts%2Fcdcfull.htm) that you can use